# on pypi.python.org what would cause hidden old versions to be returned by explicit search

Tags: python, package, pypi

I maintain the pi3d package which is available on pypi.python.org. Prior to v2.8 the latest version was always returned by a search for 'pi3d'. Subsequently v2.7 + v2.8 then v2.7 + v2.8 + v2.9 were listed. These three are still listed even though I am now at v2.10. i.e. the latest version is NOT listed and it requires sharp eyes to spot the text on the v2.9 page saying it's not the latest version!

NB all old versions are marked as 'hidden' I have tried lots of different permutations of hiding and unhiding releases, updating releases, switching on and off autohide old releases, editing the text of each release etc ad infinitum.

Is there some obvious cause of this behaviour that I have missed?

Answer (score 3):

Upon searching pypi.python.org for `pi3d` I have found that when you go to the `pi3d v2.9` page there is now a large bold warning saying that it isn't the latest version and gives a link to `v2.10` which was probably put there between the time you asked this question and now. However the fact that the `v2.10` was not listed for me shows that your problem is not a local one. Googling `site:pypi.python.org pi3d` shows `pi3d v2.10` as the first result which means that something is wrong with the `pypi` search engine.

The answer to your question is no, there is not an obvious cause of that behaviour. The fact that when I use Google I get a result as opposed to the builtin search implies that their search backend needs to be reindexed.

Comment: yes I added the message - not an entirely satisfactory solution. I know that google use algorithms that transcend any rational explanation (bing also gets it right) but I can't believe that pi3d is the only package to be scrambled by the pypi search system

Comment: It is definitely surprising that it alone was missed. If you want you could submit a bug report [here](http://bugs.python.org/). Is there anything else you want answered?

Comment: I am grateful to you for replying, thank you. However I feel that the bounty and correct answer would require some more detail about the actual issue. Also I am certain that this isn't a python bug so it would be inappropriate to stick it on the list in your link. It's either something to do with my entry or a pypi issues https://bitbucket.org/pypa/pypi/issues

Comment: No worries then, have a great day!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's just a problem with the pypi search engine, like Khush said.

Comment: Well there are a handful of issues posted on the pypi bitbucket site but not as many as I would expect if there was a wholesale 'problem with the pypi search engine' I have added some info in a comment to the most similar sounding issue post. I was hoping for some specific technical suggestions that would save me having to wade through all the pypi source, or, heaven forbid, install the whole apparatus on my laptop and figure it out myself!